# Can I run Docker containers after upgrading host?

Tags: linux, docker

I'm very new to Docker, and I'm still trying to understand the implications of using containers.

If I create a container for Docker on a Linux host, and I then upgrade the host to a newer version of Linux, will the old containers still run unchanged on the new system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you should not have any problem to run your old containers on a new fresh Linux update. I'm not aware from you current setup meaning how did you install Docker and what Linux distro are you talking about but if you've followed the rules to install Docker (as per in docs) and after upgrade/update your OS you update your packages as well then Docker should continue working.

In my case I was running Docker in Fedora 24 a few months ago and recently I moved into Fedora 25, Docker still working like a charm without any problems.

PS: If you have any problem feel free to ask here and the community will try to help you